# Storing values in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

The user is supposed to enter a name followed by grades. When the user hits -1 there can be no more grades stored for that individual. When the user types X, s/he enters the total and then -1 to indicate no more grades can be stored. I don't understand why my for loops are outputting in a weird way. The names array is storing the int values that are supposed to go to the numbers array.

For example, the input should look like this:

```
Jane 3 4 -1
Lane 4 5 -1
X   10 10 -1
```

The output should look like this:

```
Jane 3 4 
Jane had a 7/20
Lane 4 5
Lane had a 9/20
```

This is my work so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string name = " ";
 string names[20];
 int numbers[20];
 int i = 0, j=0, number;

 do
 {
   cin >> name;
   names[i]=name;
   i++;

   j=0;
   if(number!=-1)
   {
       cin>> number;
       numbers[j]=number;
       j++;
   }
 }while(name!="X");

 for(int x = 0; x <= i; x++)
 {
  for(int y = 0; y <= j; y++)
  {
      cout << names[x];
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: What is _your_ theory?

Comment: You loop over `y` without using `y`. Why?

Comment: If you're using C++ then why not use the STL?

Comment: Regarding the questions. @ Lightness : I am in the process of fixing my code. @ Marcelo : I need that other for loop later on. @ Ignacio : I would need to google STL to understand your acroymn

Comment: Take a sheet of paper and try to determine what the program does, i.e. what values the variables have etc. Especially take a look at `number` during the do-while loop.

Comment: you could also consider using a simple while instead of a do-while.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your code is ,

```
 int i = 0, j=0, number;
```

You use the uninitialised `number` in your code

```
if(number!=-1)
```

This contains garbage values which can *co-incidentally* be -1